# \centering table does not work

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I do not know where the problem is but I have issues centering tables. I have tried \centering and \begin{center} but they are still left-aligned. Does someone of you know where the problem lies?

```
  \documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Eingabekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"
\usepackage{tabularx, siunitx,booktabs, float}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}  



\begin{document}

  
 \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Ergebnisse des Martin-Loef-Tests}
    \label{tab:mltest}      
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{0.7\textwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
    l % one left aligned column
    *{3}{c} }
    \toprule
        {Dimension}&{\emph{LR}} & {\emph{df}} & {$p$}\\ \midrule
        UEBE & {331.48} & {255} & {.001}\\
        SOUE & {161.92} & {143} & {\phantom{0}.13}\\
        ERDR & {211.74} & {319} & {\phantom{0}.99}\\
        UNZU & {167.18} & {255} & {\phantom{0}.99}\\ 
        UEFO & {\phantom{1}95.37} & {143} & {\phantom{0}.99}\\
        MANG &{\phantom{1}99.40}& {63}& {.002} \\
        SOZS &{103.71}&{143}& {\phantom{0}.99}\\
        SOZI &{115.44} &{143}& {\phantom{0}.96}\\
        SORG &{\phantom{1}68.28}& {63}& {\phantom{0}.30} \\
        \bottomrule  
    \end{tabular*}
    \scriptsize{
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck; UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; 
            
            \item UEFO: Überforderung; MANG: Mangel an sozialer Anerkennung; SOZS: Soziale Spannungen; SOZI: Soziale Isolation; SORG: Chronische Besorgnis

    \end{tablenotes}}
    
 \end{table}


\begin{table}[H]    
\centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Schätzung der Itemparameter für UEBE -- MANG}
        \label{tab:itempar}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
        \footnotesize   
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
                l % one left aligned column
                *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=-1.2]}S[table-format=0.3,table-space-text-pre=$<{}$]}
            \toprule
            Items & {Lokalisation} &{$\tau_{i1}$}& {$\tau_{i2}$} &{$\tau_{i3}$}& {$\tau_{i4}$}\\ 
            \midrule

            \textbf{\emph{UEBE}} &&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 1   &1.08 &-0.82 & 0.04 & 1.89 & 3.20\\
            TICS 4  &0.96 &-1.81 & 0.14 & 2.13 & 3.37\\
            TICS 17  &0.79 &-1.76 & 0.02 & 1.97 & 2.92\\
            TICS 27  &0.91 &-1.09 & 0.78 & 1.19 & 2.75\\
            TICS 38  &0.80 &-1.94 &-0.11 & 1.87 & 3.40 \\
            TICS 44  &0.55 &-1.58 &-0.48 & 1.28 & 2.96\\
            TICS 50  &0.72 &-1.95 &-0.03 & 1.53 & 3.35\\    
            TICS 54  &0.47 &-1.75 &-0.51 & 1.44 & 2.72\\    
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{SOUE}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 7  & 0.17 &-1.23 &-0.03 &0.74 & 1.18\\
            TICS 19 & 0.83 &-0.76 &0.83  &0.95 & 2.29 \\
            TICS 28  &0.64  &-1.14 &0.45  &1.38 & 1.85\\
            TICS 39 &-0.05  &-2.03 &-0.55 &0.87 & 1.49\\
            TICS 49 &0.43   &-1.23 &0.18  &1.42 & 1.35 \\ 
            TICS 57 &0.98   &-0.92 &0.54  &1.77 & 2.52\\   
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{ERDR}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 8  & 0.54  &-1.67 &-0.05 &1.63 &2.25\\
            TICS 12 & 0.81  &-1.73 & 0.35 &2.09 &2.54\\
            TICS 14 & 0.75  &-1.21 & 0.25 &1.82 &2.16\\  
            TICS 22 & 0.38  &-1.86 & 0.54 &0.61 &2.24\\ 
            TICS 23 & 0.22  &-1.44 & -0.30&0.57 &2.04\\
            TICS 30 & 0.61  &-1.94 & -0.07&1.58 &2.86\\ 
            TICS 32 &1.27   &-0.76 & 0.76 &2.07 &2.99\\ 
            TICS 40 &0.98   &-1.05 & 0.54 &1.54 &2.88\\ 
            TICS 43 &0.41   &-2.15 & 0.08 &1.46 &2.26\\ 
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{UNZU}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 5  &0.21 &-1.25 &-0.53 &1.00 &1.61\\
            TICS 10 &0.30 &-1.41 &-0.69 &1.44 &1.85\\
            TICS 13 &-0.13&-3.04 &-0.54 &1.41 &1.63\\
            TICS 21 &0.84 &-0.84 &0.44  &1.89 &1.89\\
            TICS 37 & 1.49&0.24  &1.32  &2.14 &2.26 \\
            TICS 41 &0.79 &-1.24 &0.61  &2.16 &1.64\\
            TICS 48 &0.34 &-1.59 &-0.23 &0.88 &2.30\\   
            TICS 53 &0.45 &-1.27 &0.27  &1.80 &0.99\\   
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{UEFO}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 3    & 0.91   & -2.24 & 0.73 & 2.69 & 2.45\\
            TICS 20   & 1.31   &-1.41  & 1.42 & 2.47 & 2.74 \\
            TICS 24  &0.87      &-1.32  & 0.38 & 2.31 & 2.10\\
            TICS 35 & 0.58      &-2.63  & 0.20 & 2.64 & 2.11\\
            TICS 47 & 0.09      &-2.49  &-0.17 & 0.85 & 2.20\\ 
            TICS 55 & 0.63      &-2.12  &0.57  & 1.86 & 2.21\\   
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{MANG}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 2   &0.34  & -3.16 &-0.48 & 1.72 & 3.29\\
            TICS 18  &1.37 &-1.64  &0.82  & 2.56 & 3.75\\
            TICS 31  &1.13 &-1.85  &0.53  & 2.59 & 3.27\\    
            TICS 46  &0.84 &-2.00  &0.10  & 2.35 & 2.91\\ 
            \bottomrule     
        \end{tabular*} 

        
    \end{threeparttable}
    \scriptsize{
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck; UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; UEFO: Überforderung; MANG: Mangel an sozialer Anerkennung; SOZS: Soziale Spannungen; SOZI: Soziale Isolation; SORG: Chronische Besorgnis
    \end{tablenotes}}

\end{table} 




\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Unrelated: `\scriptsize` does not take arguments. Additionally I would probably not use `tabular*` here

Comment: Unrelated, but why did you use `siunitx` in the second table, but not in the first one? You could remove all the `\phantom` commands if you used `siunitx`. Please also clarify: Do you want caption and table notes to be as wide as the table or as wide as the whole textwidth. Why did you stretch the table to be that wide? Couldn't you place the long versions of the abbreviations in the table itself instead of below it? What's the reason to use `\footnotesize` for the first table? It would fit perfectly if you used a normalsize font.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give `\centering` before `threeparttable`, modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Eingabekodierung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"
\usepackage{threeparttable,tabularx, siunitx,booktabs, float}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}                      
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}  

\begin{document}

  
 \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Ergebnisse des Martin-Loef-Tests}
    \label{tab:mltest}      
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{0.7\textwidth}{
        @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
    l % one left aligned column
    *{3}{c} }
    \toprule
        {Dimension}&{\emph{LR}} & {\emph{df}} & {$p$}\\ \midrule
        UEBE & {331.48} & {255} & {.001}\\
        SOUE & {161.92} & {143} & {\phantom{0}.13}\\
        ERDR & {211.74} & {319} & {\phantom{0}.99}\\
        UNZU & {167.18} & {255} & {\phantom{0}.99}\\ 
        UEFO & {\phantom{1}95.37} & {143} & {\phantom{0}.99}\\
        MANG &{\phantom{1}99.40}& {63}& {.002} \\
        SOZS &{103.71}&{143}& {\phantom{0}.99}\\
        SOZI &{115.44} &{143}& {\phantom{0}.96}\\
        SORG &{\phantom{1}68.28}& {63}& {\phantom{0}.30} \\
        \bottomrule  
    \end{tabular*}
    \scriptsize{
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck; UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; 
            
            \item UEFO: Überforderung; MANG: Mangel an sozialer Anerkennung; SOZS: Soziale Spannungen; SOZI: Soziale Isolation; SORG: Chronische Besorgnis
    \end{tablenotes}}
\end{threeparttable}    
 \end{table}


\begin{table}[H]    
\centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Schätzung der Itemparameter für UEBE -- MANG}
        \label{tab:itempar}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
        \footnotesize   
        \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{
                @{\extracolsep{\fill}}% fill the space between columns
                l % one left aligned column
                *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=-1.2]}S[table-format=0.3,table-space-text-pre=$<{}$]}
            \toprule
            Items & {Lokalisation} &{$\tau_{i1}$}& {$\tau_{i2}$} &{$\tau_{i3}$}& {$\tau_{i4}$}\\ 
            \midrule

            \textbf{\emph{UEBE}} &&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 1   &1.08 &-0.82 & 0.04 & 1.89 & 3.20\\
            TICS 4  &0.96 &-1.81 & 0.14 & 2.13 & 3.37\\
            TICS 17  &0.79 &-1.76 & 0.02 & 1.97 & 2.92\\
            TICS 27  &0.91 &-1.09 & 0.78 & 1.19 & 2.75\\
            TICS 38  &0.80 &-1.94 &-0.11 & 1.87 & 3.40 \\
            TICS 44  &0.55 &-1.58 &-0.48 & 1.28 & 2.96\\
            TICS 50  &0.72 &-1.95 &-0.03 & 1.53 & 3.35\\    
            TICS 54  &0.47 &-1.75 &-0.51 & 1.44 & 2.72\\    
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{SOUE}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 7  & 0.17 &-1.23 &-0.03 &0.74 & 1.18\\
            TICS 19 & 0.83 &-0.76 &0.83  &0.95 & 2.29 \\
            TICS 28  &0.64  &-1.14 &0.45  &1.38 & 1.85\\
            TICS 39 &-0.05  &-2.03 &-0.55 &0.87 & 1.49\\
            TICS 49 &0.43   &-1.23 &0.18  &1.42 & 1.35 \\ 
            TICS 57 &0.98   &-0.92 &0.54  &1.77 & 2.52\\   
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{ERDR}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 8  & 0.54  &-1.67 &-0.05 &1.63 &2.25\\
            TICS 12 & 0.81  &-1.73 & 0.35 &2.09 &2.54\\
            TICS 14 & 0.75  &-1.21 & 0.25 &1.82 &2.16\\  
            TICS 22 & 0.38  &-1.86 & 0.54 &0.61 &2.24\\ 
            TICS 23 & 0.22  &-1.44 & -0.30&0.57 &2.04\\
            TICS 30 & 0.61  &-1.94 & -0.07&1.58 &2.86\\ 
            TICS 32 &1.27   &-0.76 & 0.76 &2.07 &2.99\\ 
            TICS 40 &0.98   &-1.05 & 0.54 &1.54 &2.88\\ 
            TICS 43 &0.41   &-2.15 & 0.08 &1.46 &2.26\\ 
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{UNZU}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 5  &0.21 &-1.25 &-0.53 &1.00 &1.61\\
            TICS 10 &0.30 &-1.41 &-0.69 &1.44 &1.85\\
            TICS 13 &-0.13&-3.04 &-0.54 &1.41 &1.63\\
            TICS 21 &0.84 &-0.84 &0.44  &1.89 &1.89\\
            TICS 37 & 1.49&0.24  &1.32  &2.14 &2.26 \\
            TICS 41 &0.79 &-1.24 &0.61  &2.16 &1.64\\
            TICS 48 &0.34 &-1.59 &-0.23 &0.88 &2.30\\   
            TICS 53 &0.45 &-1.27 &0.27  &1.80 &0.99\\   
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{UEFO}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 3    & 0.91   & -2.24 & 0.73 & 2.69 & 2.45\\
            TICS 20   & 1.31   &-1.41  & 1.42 & 2.47 & 2.74 \\
            TICS 24  &0.87      &-1.32  & 0.38 & 2.31 & 2.10\\
            TICS 35 & 0.58      &-2.63  & 0.20 & 2.64 & 2.11\\
            TICS 47 & 0.09      &-2.49  &-0.17 & 0.85 & 2.20\\ 
            TICS 55 & 0.63      &-2.12  &0.57  & 1.86 & 2.21\\   
            \addlinespace
            \textbf{\emph{MANG}}&&&&&\\ \midrule
            TICS 2   &0.34  & -3.16 &-0.48 & 1.72 & 3.29\\
            TICS 18  &1.37 &-1.64  &0.82  & 2.56 & 3.75\\
            TICS 31  &1.13 &-1.85  &0.53  & 2.59 & 3.27\\    
            TICS 46  &0.84 &-2.00  &0.10  & 2.35 & 2.91\\ 
            \bottomrule     
        \end{tabular*} 
    \scriptsize{
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \item UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck; UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; UEFO: Überforderung; MANG: Mangel an sozialer Anerkennung; SOZS: Soziale Spannungen; SOZI: Soziale Isolation; SORG: Chronische Besorgnis
    \end{tablenotes}}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 




\end{document}
```

Comment: @daleif Thanks, updated....

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It has worked out now.

Answer (score 0):

your second table is to tall that can be fit on one page. Therefore I suggest to use `xtabular` where width of columns in your tables with numbers are determined  by column headers containing `X` column type. In both tables I suggest to use `S` column that numbers are aligned at decimal points, so you can remove all `phantom` commands in the first table.

For legend below tables you not need `threeparttable` table, it can be in minipage environment:

Second table is manually break onto two pages. By this you can (after first compilation) decide, where is the most appropriate place for this.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       % Fontkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    % deutsche Sprachenunterstützung; Doku: "gerdoc"
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries} % kleinere Beschriftungen
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Ergebnisse des Martin-Loef-Tests}
    \label{tab:mltest}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{
        l % one left aligned column
        S[table-format=3.2]
        S[table-format=3.0]
        S[table-format=1.4]
                    }
        \toprule
    Dimension& \mcx{\emph{LR}}
                        & \mcx{\emph{df}}
                                & \mcx{$p$}\\
    \midrule
        UEBE & 331.48   & 255   & .001  \\
        SOUE & 161.92   & 143   & .13   \\
        ERDR & 211.74   & 319   & .99   \\
        UNZU & 167.18   & 255   & .99   \\
        UEFO &  95.37   & 143   & .99   \\
        MANG &  99.40   &  63   & .002  \\
        SOZS & 103.71   & 143   & .99   \\
        SOZI & 115.44   & 143   & .96   \\
        SORG &  68.28   & 63    & .30   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}\scriptsize
    \textbf{Legende:}\\
UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck; UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; UEFO: Überforderung; MANG: Mangel an sozialer Anerkennung; SOZS: Soziale Spannungen; SOZI: Soziale Isolation; SORG: Chronische Besorgnis
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\newpage
\begingroup
    \begin{xltabular}{0.75\textwidth}{l
                               *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2]}
                               *{2}{S[table-format= 1.2]}
                                    }
    \caption{Schätzung der Itemparameter für UEBE -- MANG}
    \label{tab:itempar} \\
        \toprule
    Items    & \mcx{Lokal.}
                    & \mcx {$\tau_{i1}$}
                            & \mcx{$\tau_{i2}$}
                                  & \mcx{$\tau_{i3}$}
                                         & \mcx{$\tau_{i4}$}\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{MSchätzung der Itemparameter für UEBE -- MANG (cont.)} \\
    \toprule
    Items    & \mcx{Lokal.}
                    & \mcx {$\tau_{i1}$}
                            & \mcx{$\tau_{i2}$}
                                  & \mcx{$\tau_{i3}$}
                                         & \mcx{$\tau_{i4}$}\\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
\multicolumn{6}{>{\footnotesize\itshape}r}{continue on the next page}\\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% table body
    \textbf{\emph{UEBE}} &&&&&\\
        \midrule
    TICS 1   & 1.08 &-0.82 & 0.04 & 1.89 & 3.20\\
    TICS 4   & 0.96 &-1.81 & 0.14 & 2.13 & 3.37\\
    TICS 17  & 0.79 &-1.76 & 0.02 & 1.97 & 2.92\\
    TICS 27  & 0.91 &-1.09 & 0.78 & 1.19 & 2.75\\
    TICS 38  & 0.80 &-1.94 &-0.11 & 1.87 & 3.40\\
    TICS 44  & 0.55 &-1.58 &-0.48 & 1.28 & 2.96\\
    TICS 50  & 0.72 &-1.95 &-0.03 & 1.53 & 3.35\\
    TICS 54  & 0.47 &-1.75 &-0.51 & 1.44 & 2.72\\
        \addlinespace
    \textbf{\emph{SOUE}}&&&&&                  \\
        \midrule
    TICS 7   & 0.17 &-1.23 &-0.03 & 0.74 & 1.18\\
    TICS 19  & 0.83 &-0.76 & 0.83 & 0.95 & 2.29\\
    TICS 28  & 0.64 &-1.14 & 0.45 & 1.38 & 1.85\\
    TICS 39  &-0.05 &-2.03 &-0.55 & 0.87 & 1.49\\
    TICS 49  & 0.43 &-1.23 & 0.18 & 1.42 & 1.35\\
    TICS 57  & 0.98 &-0.92 & 0.54 & 1.77 & 2.52\\
        \addlinespace
    \textbf{\emph{ERDR}}&&&&&                   \\
        \midrule
    TICS 8   & 0.54 &-1.67 &-0.05 & 1.63 & 2.25\\
    TICS 12  & 0.81 &-1.73 & 0.35 & 2.09 & 2.54\\
    TICS 14  & 0.75 &-1.21 & 0.25 & 1.82 & 2.16\\
    TICS 22  & 0.38 &-1.86 & 0.54 & 0.61 & 2.24\\
    TICS 23  & 0.22 &-1.44 &-0.30 & 0.57 & 2.04\\
    TICS 30  & 0.61 &-1.94 &-0.07 & 1.58 & 2.86\\
    TICS 32  & 1.27 &-0.76 & 0.76 & 2.07 & 2.99\\
    TICS 40  & 0.98 &-1.05 & 0.54 & 1.54 & 2.88\\
    TICS 43  & 0.41 &-2.15 & 0.08 & 1.46 & 2.26\\
        \addlinespace
    \textbf{\emph{UNZU}}&&&&&                  \\
        \midrule
    TICS 5  & 0.21  &-1.25 &-0.53 & 1.00 & 1.61\\
    TICS 10 & 0.30  &-1.41 &-0.69 & 1.44 & 1.85\\
    TICS 13 &-0.13  &-3.04 &-0.54 & 1.41 & 1.63\\
    TICS 21 & 0.84  &-0.84 & 0.44 & 1.89 & 1.89\\
    TICS 37 & 1.49  & 0.24 & 1.32 & 2.14 & 2.26\\
    TICS 41 & 0.79  &-1.24 & 0.61 & 2.16 & 1.64\\
    TICS 48 & 0.34  &-1.59 &-0.23 & 0.88 & 2.30\\
    TICS 53 & 0.45  &-1.27 & 0.27 & 1.80 & 0.99\\
        \pagebreak
    \textbf{\emph{UEFO}}&&&&&                   \\
        \midrule
    TICS 3  & 0.91  & -2.24 & 0.73 & 2.69 & 2.45\\
    TICS 20 & 1.31  &-1.41  & 1.42 & 2.47 & 2.74\\
    TICS 24 & 0.87  &-1.32  & 0.38 & 2.31 & 2.10\\
    TICS 35 & 0.58  &-2.63  & 0.20 & 2.64 & 2.11\\
    TICS 47 & 0.09  &-2.49  &-0.17 & 0.85 & 2.20\\
    TICS 55 & 0.63  &-2.12  & 0.57 & 1.86 & 2.21\\
        \addlinespace
    \textbf{\emph{MANG}}&&&&&                   \\
        \midrule
    TICS 2  & 0.34  & -3.16 &-0.48 & 1.72 & 3.29\\
    TICS 18 & 1.37  &-1.64  & 0.82 & 2.56 & 3.75\\
    TICS 31 & 1.13  &-1.85  & 0.53 & 2.59 & 3.27\\
    TICS 46 & 0.84  &-2.00  & 0.10 & 2.35 & 2.91\\
    \end{xltabular}\vspace{-2ex}
    
\noindent\hfil\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}\scriptsize
    \textbf{Legende:}\\
Lokal.: Lokalisation; UEBE: Arbeitsüberlastung; SOUE: Soziale Überlastung; ERDR: Erfolgsdruck; UNZU: Arbeitsunzufriedenheit; UEFO: Überforderung; MANG: Mangel an sozialer Anerkennung; SOZS: Soziale Spannungen; SOZI: Soziale Isolation; SORG: Chronische Besorgnis
    \end{minipage}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]